# How to use transform scale to make letter larger than "bolder"

Tags: html, css

I want to make a letter with a large girth but using transform scale doesn't work. It either makes the letter wide or long.

```
<div class="g">g</div>

@media(min-width: 768px){.g {font-size: 500px; position: 
relative; bottom: 435px; left: 550px;font-weight: bolder}}
```

Tried:

```
@media(min-width: 768px){.g {font-size: 500px; position: 
relative; bottom: 435px; left: 550px;font-weight: bolder; 
transform:scale(2.0,1.0)}}
```

But, as mentioned, alters width/height not girth.

Comment: what did you actually want to do i cant understand can you please explain it more?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/girth

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `text-stroke`

```css
.g {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 10px black; 
  text-stroke: 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="g">g</div>
```

Comment: Css doesn't recognise `text-stroke` or `-webkit-text-stroke` It's an `unknown property` according to lint

Comment: @Animate1 run the code here and you will see it's working unless you are using IE

Answer (score 0):

You should add scale(1.1)

**css**

```
.g {font-size: 500px; position: 
relative; bottom: 435px; left: 550px;font-weight: bolder;transform: scale(1.1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can make the font boldest with `font-weight: 1000` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight). However you also need to use a font, that supports that weight.